# Java Comparing Objects ints against each other to find an exact result

Tags: java, arrays, ranking

I am currently trying to make a Race Car Simulator in order to learn some Java. I have made objects of each driver and their cars:

```
public static Driver drivers[] = new Driver[18];
```

Each driver gets many values which decide how well he did for a race:

```
    int overall;
    int rating;

    int corners;
    int straightaways;
    int rain;
    int skill;
    int experience;
    int pace;
    int awareness;
```

Then when I go to the race state and try and simulate the first race I get the variable of the drivers Overall (value is 50 - 100 ) and I add a "Luck" factor to that Overall to get the results.

```
package races;

import racers.CreateDrivers;
import racers.Driver;

public class RaceSimulator {
    
    //duplicating drivers Array... Do not know if I need this.
    public Driver currentRace[] = CreateDrivers.drivers.clone(); 
    
    public static void SimulateNextRace() {
        
        System.out.println("\nFirst Race is Beginning!!\n");
        
        int racedayLuck;
        int raceFinishUnsorted;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < CreateDrivers.drivers.length; i++) {
            racedayLuck = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
            
            raceFinishUnsorted = racedayLuck + CreateDrivers.drivers[i].getOverall();
                        
            CreateDrivers.drivers[i].setRacedayFinish(raceFinishUnsorted);
            System.out.println(CreateDrivers.drivers[i].getName() + ": " + CreateDrivers.drivers[i].getRacedayFinish());
        }
        
        //TODO Trying to Rank the drivers against each other and set drivers[i].setPoint 
    }
    
    public static void getRank() {
        //
    }
    
}
```

Example Console Output:

```
First Race is Beginning!!

Joseph Morgan: 90
Malachi Nguyen: 90
Greg Hart: 76
Ian Banks: 78
Gabriel Mcdonald: 84
Spencer Meyer: 94
Jordan Soto: 95
Abraham Wells: 94
Charles Frederiks: 82
Trevor Fleming: 92
Nathaniel Nguyen: 67
Johnathan Herrera: 79
Derek Miller: 88
Grant Reynolds: 86
Kyle Bailey: 82
Conner Sullivan: 98
Paul Perry: 96
Antonio Larson: 87
```

I cannot figure out how to rank all values of "CreateDrivers.drivers[x]" against each other without sorting it.

In other words: How do I go about ranking the drivers, without changing any values, but also allowing myself to add to their "Seasonal Points"

I tried by adding an "id" value to Drivers and sorting this value as an array and finding the ids again... But it just seems as there must be a much easier way to rank 18 ints against one another.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want a list of drivers sorted by raceDayFinish?

Comment: I want to give each driver points based on the highest Raceday Value

Comment: And exactly what problem are you having doing this?

Comment: Once I sort the array, it no longer keeps the sorting that I need for my other functions. Hence, without sorting. :)

Comment: How do you difine a rank? First with the highest score to last with the least? And what if two drivers have the same score? Do they have the same rank aswell?

Comment: You still haven't explained your issue very clearly, but perhaps this is what you want:

"After each race, rank the ten drivers with the highest racedayFinish scores. Add to the driver's seasonPoints the number [25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1] depending on their rank."

Comment: Thank you for explaining it much better than me. @tgdavies

Answer (score 1):

I quite don't understand what you want to do but I thought you want to get the ranking of the race You can just sort the array by `Driver.getRacedayFinish();` using comparator in java and assign its index + 1 its rank like:-

```
   Arrays.sort(CreateDrivers.drivers, new Comparator<Integer>(){
    @Override
   public int compare(Driver d1, Driver d2) {
       // You can create compareTo method for that but I will just use this
       if (d1.getRacedayFinish() == d2.getRacedayFinish()) return 0;
       else if (d1.getRacedayFinish() < d2.getRacedayFinish()) return -1; 
      return 1;
    }
   });
```

This Will sort the array then you just need to assign its indexs as its rank like:-

```
for (int i = 1; i <= drivers.length; i++) {
    drivers.setPoint[i-1] = i;
  }
```

I hope I give you that answer which you are looking for if you don't get what you are looking for then you can explain more clearly in the question section.